# How can I fix the issue with this for loop?

Tags: r

I am looping through shapefiles to calculate home-range overlap with treatment area. The loop runs great until it runs  `pi <- st_intersection(treatment, home.range.t)` on a home-range with 0 overlap, at which point I get the following error: `` Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = numeric(0)) :  replacement has 0 rows, data has 2 `` Is it possible to separate home-ranges with 0 overlap before running `st_intersection`? Or, better yet enter a 0 in those with no overlap and keep moving? Code below. I have marked ##### on the line producing the error. Thank you!

````
#read in and create list of home ranges
home.names <- list.files("C:\\Users\\kujld016\\Desktop\\All\\Projects\\Brush_Management\\KingR_BBM", 
                         pattern="*.shp", recursive=T, full.names=T)
#str(home.names)


#####################################################
#create list to hold results and loop home-range overlap calculations
all.home.ranges <- list()

#loop
for (i in 21){
  home.range <- st_read(home.names[i])
  home.range$Id <- print(file.path(home.names[i]))
  home.range$Id <- substr(home.range$Id, 75,97)
  home.range.t <- st_transform(home.range,'+proj=utm +zone=14 
        +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')
  pi <- st_intersection(treatment, home.range.t)  ###produces empty columns for home-range with 0 overlap###
  home.range$percent_area <- as.numeric(st_area(pi) / st_area(home.range.t) *100) ####error###
  home.range <- subset(home.range, home.range$percent_area < 99.9)
  all.home.ranges[[i]] <- home.range
}

#create data frame of home-ranges
BB_homeranges<-ldply(all.home.ranges)
summary(BB_homeranges)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test `pi` before trying to assign to `percent_area`. I'm not sure what `st_intersection` returns but from your comment, I'm guessing a `data.frame`. Assuming that, could try something such as

```
pi <- st_intersection(treatment, home.range.t)

if(NROWS(pi) != 0){
  home.range$percent_area <- as.numeric(st_area(pi) / st_area(home.range.t) *100)
} else {
  home.range$percent_area <- 0
}
```

Comment: @ Marcus, your code worked perfectly, and I can say I am officially done with this analysis. I appreciate your help very much!